# How to use a fetch in CakePHP 2?

Tags: cakephp-2.0

How to use a fetch in CakePHP 2?

The default action for the connection using

```
  echo $ this-> fetch ('content');
```

And how to use the fetch include leftmenu.ctp?

So do not get

```
  echo $ this-> fetch ('leftmenu');
```

Comment: Krava seems forgot to response to your question. Please have a close look to my solution. It may me helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you should use leftmenu as an element. In Elements folder place the ctp file and include it like this:

```
echo $this->element('leftmenu');
```